# Where to set the OAuth redirect_uri in ASP.NET 4.5 webforms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, oauth-2.0

I can't find anywhere how to set the OAuth2 redirect_uri in an ASP.NET 4.5 webforms application. By default it's set to localhost and of course I get this error from google:

```
The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:3884/signin-google did not 
match a registered redirect URI
```

And this from Facebook:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the
given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL
or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

And I get this error from my website domain (not from the localhost).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was testing the built in external login logic for authentication, and I got this error even though my Google API credentials were correct. For example the redirect URI was set to:

`http://localhost:29405/signin-google`

The odd thing was that the default CallbackPath for the Google Authentication is "/signin-google" but I had to set this anyway in App_Start/Startup.Auth, so I added this line and it worked:

> **CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-google")**

so...

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "YOUR CLIENT ID",
            ClientSecret = "YOUR CLIENT SECRET",
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-google")
        });
```

Comment: Did anyone work out why this is required? It fixed the issue for me, but I'm wondering why we needed it.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and I am breaking my head trying to understand there this "signin-google" is coming from. Global text search in all files in my project didnt find any "signin-google" occurrences.

Comment: I would give 10 upvotes if I could. Thank you for the correct and simple fix !

Comment: 2022, and this helped me, was scratching my head at work for this for a long time LOL!

Answer (score 13):

After looking at a lot of answers this is what worked for me:

1. Enable Google + API
2. The default redirect URI is /signin-google, so add this to the Authorized redirect URI. 
   [image]
3. Add this to the RouteConfig File:

   routes.MapRoute(name: "signin-google", url: "signin-google", defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "ExternalLoginCallback" });

Hope it helps anyone that cross by this problem.

Comment: Gold star for you sir, I forgot to add the route and this helped me.

Comment: I did all that but I still get the same error, maybe u can suggest what I am doing wrong, here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664250/visual-studio-2013-mvc5-web-app-project-results-in-redirect-uri-mismatch-error

Comment: I did a global search in all files in my project for "signin-google" and nothing was found. Where is this "signin-google" coming from ? And to what is it mapped, I didnt see any controller or action that this redirect is supposed to hit on callback.

Comment: @monstro after an user authenticates, google redirect the user back to yourdomain.com/signin-google by default, this wasn't supposed to be found anywhere in your code. You could follow this answer and map a route so when google redirected an user back to this url, your router would internally dispatch the call to `ExternalLoginCallback()` action in your `AccountController`. If you don't know where to create a map to your routes, I'd suggest you learning the basics of it before start using external providers at all (imho).

Comment: It would have been nice if MS added that line in RouteConfig.cs but commented it out for us.

Comment: mapping routes never mentioned in all tutorials i read , thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

You have to enable `Google+ API` (it's not enabled by default).

[image: Enable Google+ API]
[https://console.developers.google.com/project/*projectId*/apiui/apiview/plus](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_projectId_/apiui/apiview/plus)

Default *CallbackPath* (`/signin-google`) is ok, but you have to add it to *REDIRECT URIS* at Credentials - OAuth ClientID (you can replace the default `/oauth2callback`).

Comment: It's enabled, but still does not work I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Also need to turn the **SSL ON**

I did what [thenninger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25328134/790795) and  [Sanchitos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29946310/790795) posted.

But only after i run my webApp with SSL then it worked.

You can turn on SSL in project properties here:

[image]

And make sure application starts on correct address:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I needed to add in more of the path the route, as follow:

```
 routes.MapRoute(name: "signin-google", url: "localhost:44336/signin-google", defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "ExternalLoginCallback" });
```